# C# P\Invoke DLL no entry point into C++?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a C++ Dll "TheFoo.dll" with a method "Foo()"

I have access to other C++ code that uses this method by simply calling:

```
Foo();
```

I believe the Method does have the:

```
 __declspec( dllexport )
```

So, with the reading I've done about P/Invoke, i thought i should be able to simply call the same method from my C# code:

```
namespace PInvokeExample1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        [DllImport(@"C:\MyFolder\TheFoo.dll")]
        public static extern
            void Foo();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Foo();

        }



    }
}
```

When i run it, i get an error:

```
Unable to find an entry point named 'Foo' in DLL 'C:\MyFolder\TheFoo.dll'.
```

Any ideas why it is not found?

Comment: Is `Foo()` a global function in C++, or is it a class member method? Note that the word "method" only applies to class member functions, not global functions. Also be aware of name-mangling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should provide more information on your C++. Try using `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)` instead. C++ exports with strange names so using `extern "C"` avoids that.

Comment: Note that you'll probably also have to specify the calling convention on the C# side, since C++ will default to `cdecl`, but PInvoke defaults to `StdCall`

Comment: Thanks Rohan, that explains it.

Answer (score 10):

The C++ language supports overloading, much like C# does.  You could export an function `void Foo(int)` and a function `void Foo(double)`.  Clearly those two functions could not both be exported as "Foo", the client of the DLL wouldn't know which one to pick.  So it is not.

The C++ compiler solves that problem by *decorating* the name of the function.  Adding extra characters that makes a Foo(int) different from a Foo(double).  You can see those decorated names by running `Dumpbin.exe /exports foo.dll` from the Visual Studio Command Prompt, that lists the name of the exported functions.  Assuming your declaration was relevant, you'd see `?Foo@@YAXXZ`.

So the corresponding declaration in your C# program should be:

```
    [DllImport("foo.dll", EntryPoint = "?Foo@@YAXXZ", 
               ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void Foo();
```

There are ways to change the C++ function declaration to make the C# declaration easier.  Which is actually not a good idea, these decorated names actually help catch mistakes.

Comment: What happens if the declaration in C# mismatches the EntryPoint field? If `"?Foo@@YAXXZ"` is `Foo(int)`, what happens if a 1.`void Foo(double)` or 2."Foo()" in your example is declared in C#?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't declare it extern "C" in your dll, its name has likely been "mangled".  You can use something like Dependency Walker to see what symbols your dll exports.