# How to use a DLL written in Visual C++ in a C# program?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# P\Invoke DLL no entry point into C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592113/c-sharp-p-invoke-dll-no-entry-point-into-c)

I'm asking this question after doing a rather thorough surfing on SO and google, and most of the answers get me about 80% of the way, but its still a bit confusing, so kindly show me the way out.

I have some Visual C++ functions defined as follows:

---

**MyDLL.h**

```
#ifdef FUNCTIONS_EXPORTS
#define FUNCTIONS_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define FUNCTIONS_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

namespace Functions {
    class MyFunctions {
    public:
        static FUNCTIONS_API int Add(int a, int b);
        static FUNCTIONS_API int Factorial(int a);
    };
}
```

---

**MyDLL.cpp**

```
namespace Functions {
    int MyFunctions::Add (int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
    int MyFunctions::Factorial (int a)
    {
        if(a<0)
            return -1;
        else if(a==0 || a==1)
            return 1;
        else
            return a*MyFunctions::Factorial(a-1);
    }
}
```

---

Now, I want to import the DLL generated by this build into my C# program as such:

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DLLTester
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("path\\to\\the\dll\\myDLL.dll")]
        public static extern int Factorial(int a);
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int num;
            num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("The factorial is " + Factorial(num));
        }
    }
}
```

---

I've tried writing the functions without a class (no `static` keyword while defining), but even that does not work and gives errors.

Where am I going wrong in all this?

Comment: There's a mechanism in .NET for calling into the Windows API and unmanaged code called PInvoke ("platform invoke"). SO should be able to help you here, if not there's also a helpful wiki for using PInvoke interop at http://pinvoke.net 


Now, I have never used DLLImport so I'm not saying this will work but perhaps try to use unsigned int with your call into the C++ code. ie. 

static extern UInt32 Factorial(UInt32 a);

Comment: Additionally to Patrick's answer you might want to specify `__stdcall` on your C++ methods. Otherwise you will get errors when returning from the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem I see is that you're trying to p/invoke class methods.  Because of [C++ name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B), the entry point you supplied isn't present in your compiled DLL.  You should be able to run `dumpbin.exe` on your DLL and see for yourself.

When using C++ classes I've always followed the pattern of creating "manager" methods on the C++ side that handle creation of C++ classes.  The creation method creates an object (on the C++ side), stores it in an array, and returns an integer Id that I use to make further calls with that instance.  [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18032/How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class) outlines an approach similar to this, and also covers using the class instance directly (this method relies on importing the mangled name which should be deterministic when using a single compiler).

I'd suggest skimming the name mangling article and how to prevent it for `DllImport` purposes, and read most of the CodeProject article linked in the previous paragraph.  It's pretty well written and covers a lot of p/invoke minutiae.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

I actually referred to the answer given in this quesion,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592113/c-sharp-p-invoke-dll-no-entry-point-into-c

which explains it in a lot clearer way.